# use tika in nutch plugin

Tags: apache, parsing, nutch, apache-tika

In nutch I'm implementing a plug-in that will get the content of webpages and process them in special way.

My main problem is I want to convert webpages to plainText to be able to processed,, I read that tika toolkit can do that

so, I found this code that use tika to parse urls, I write it under filter method

```
 public ParseResult filter(Content content, ParseResult parseResult, HTMLMetaTags metaTags, DocumentFragment doc) 
  {
 byte[] raw = content.getContent();
 ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
 Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(); 
 parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(raw), handler, metadata, new ParseContext());
 String plainText = handler.toString(); 
 LOG.info("Mime: " + metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE));
 LOG.info("content: " + handler.toString());

      }
```

The result of metadata.get(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE) is text/html

but handler.toString() is empty !

Update:
Also I try to use this line after the parser method

```
 LOG.info ("Status : "+ new ParseStatus().toString());
```

and I get this result:
Status : notparsed(0,0)

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.1 Nutch includes a [Tika plugin](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/TikaPlugin) (see also [NUTCH-766](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-766)) that should cover your need. I don't know if there's more comprehensive documentation available. You might want to ask the [Nutch users](http://nutch.apache.org/mailing_lists.html) mailing list for more details (or someone here on SO can fill in).

Comment: Thank you, I've asked a question in the mailing list but nobody answered me. Is there any helpful resources or snapshot of code that may help?

Answer (score 0):

As Jukka Zitting said, `Tika` is already leveraged in nutch. In the code that you pasted, there is no place that you had set the `metadata` and `ParseStatus` to any nutch specific data structure. So you dont see the `ParseStatus` accordingly.